How to Convert USD test stripe balance to crypto currency/Matic automatically via code on the Blockchain?
I have integrated stripe code where user pay in USD test funds via stripe on subscription, I want to convert the user USD into MATIC, which should then be deposited into my wallet address on the blockchain.
Challenge: How can I efficiently convert USD from a traditional payment system into MATIC automatically via code?, I'm looking for an example code - I have explored stripe fiat-to-Crypto onboard, its a new feature which give this facility but its asking bank accounts so I cannot test my code via fiat-to-Crypto
Thanks

You’re doing that conversion off-chain?

Right now i'm not doing any conversion, I just exploring solution so that i can test it with testing funds.
Currently when user subscribes and stripe charges a fee from user in dollars that code is done, now i want to do conversion Usd to Matic.
One thing I can do is I can remove the stripe part and can do with solidity, In that case user will need to deposit USDC to contract and then i will swap USDC to MATIC, Correct me Asad if I'm wrong.

I have explored the stripe documentation, we can do conversion from USDC To MATIC but we cannot test it via code, we can only test it with real funds, but with smart contract we can test, but user will need to pay the gas fee in that case to deposit USDC.

After reasearch I found that with stripe we can do conversion from USDC to MAtic via stripe connect and  USD bank account to Crypto via onramp with real currencies not with test funds.

I think, doing it on-chain using a solidity contract, would be better, for transparency purposes. And, you don’t need to ask the users to deposit USDC, they can directly deposit MATIC (equivalent to the intended USD amount) as native token if you’re deploying your contract on Polygon. However, if you want to deal with a stable value, then you can go ahead with depositing USDC or any stable ERC20 instead of the native token.

Yesterday, you’d asked a similar question, to which I answered with an example showcasing the usage of Chainlink Price Feed for your use-case. But, I think, you’ve deleted that question.

yes i deleted Sorry for that.

Okay Asad, right now first priority is to do via stripe, Can you help in stripe case ?

yess Asad with soldiity is the last final solution, you are correct instead of USDC users can give directly via Matic as contract will be on POLYGON.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
